# jQuery autosuggest using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

first question is that i have an auto complete it works find  when i complete type the first name it load perfect but when i press space to continue to type the lastname the div hides and doesn't continued with the search result.i am missing something in the php file or the jquery file.

this is the search bar

```
<form method='post' action='index2.php#profile_info.php'>
    <input type="text"  id='inputSearch' placeholder="Search"  autocomplete="off" class="search" />
    <input type='submit' id='Search_Submit' value='' />
</form>
<div id="divResult"</div>
```

this is the search.php file to query the database

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, email, country, gender from users where firstname like '%$q%' OR lastname like '%$q%' order by email_activated='1' LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{

$id = $row['user_id'];  
$firstname=$row['firstname'];
$lastname=$row['lastname'];
$email=$row['email'];
$country=$row['country'];
$Gender=$row['gender'];
$cacheBuster = rand(999999999,9999999999999);

$check_pic = "members/$id/image01.jpg";
    $default_pic = "members/image01.jpg";
    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
    $users_pic ="$check_pic?$cacheBuster"; // forces picture to be 100px wide and no more
    }else {
    $users_pic = "images/profiles/".$Gender."_small.jpg"; // forces default picture to be 100px wide and no more

}

$b_firstname='<b>' .$q. '</b>';
$b_lastname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$final_firstname = str_ireplace( $q, $b_firstname, $firstname);
$final_lastname = str_ireplace( $q, $b_lastname, $lastname);
?>
<div class="display_box" align="left" >
<a href="http://localhost/MyNewSite/index2.php?user_id='<?php echo $id; ?>'#status.php" target="_self"> <img src="<?php echo $users_pic; ?>" style="width:55px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" /></a><span class="name"><a href="http://localhost/MyNewSite/index2.php?user_id='<?php echo $id; ?>'#status.php" target="_self" class="friendsLink"><?php echo " $final_firstname $final_lastname"; ?> </a></span>&nbsp;<br/><span style="font-size:10px; margin-left:6px;"><?php echo $email; ?></span><br/>
<span style="font-size:10px; color:#C40000; margin-left:6px;"><?php echo $country; ?></span></div>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

and the jquery to load the div

```
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var inputSearch = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'searchword='+ inputSearch;
if(inputSearch!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#divResult").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#divResult").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#divResult").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#inputSearch').click(function(){
    jQuery("#divResult").fadeIn();
});
});


jQuery(function($){
   $("#inputSearch").Watermark("Search");
   });
```

Comment: is there a reason you're not using the jquery UI autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When you type space after first name, it can't return anything, since the search phrase is passed as is and is looked up in `firstname` and `lastname` columns separately. Look at your query:

```
SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, email, country, gender 
from users 
where firstname like '%$q%' OR lastname like '%$q%'  /* <- here's the problem */
order by email_activated='1' LIMIT 5
```

If you have John Smith in your table, he won't be found, since `"John"` **is not like** `"%John %"`.

You will need to change the where clause. You might try:

```
where firstname + ' ' + lastname like '%$q%' or
      lastname + ' ' + firstname like '%$q%'
```

Comment: thanks Michal Klouda for the tip but i tried it but it not giving any result and the div isnt loading out neither to show the result

Answer (score 0):

it was the where query and much thanks to Michal Klouda for the tip where the problem lies.

```
$sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, email, country, gender
FROM users where lower(concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname)) like '%$q%' ORDER BY email_activated =  '1'
LIMIT 5");
```